# Why am I getting a syntax error at this prevState statement when I try to deploy my React App?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, syntax-error, jsx

I'm trying to deploy this React App, but it's having trouble getting past this statement:

```
useEffect(() => {
> 34 |     setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, calls: fetchedCalls }));
     |                                ^
  35 |   }, [fetchedCalls]);
```

Specifically at the ...prevState part. I have two other similar statements and if I remove this one it has a problem with the other two. The error is SyntaxError: ... Unexpected token (34:31).

I've tried removing this specific statement but I'm still getting errors for the other two either way, and I don't think it's a problem with brackets or parentheses because the VS Code isn't pulling up any errors, just when I try to deploy.

This what my setState looks like:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
view: "Feed",
back: null,
id: null,
call: null,
calls: [],});
```